# Comments timestamps can give away a review audit

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review-audits

I just got [this review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7334805) in the Triage queue. This is what it looked like before I clicked anything:

> [image]

The votes have been removed and the question timestamp reset to hide its audit status, but the comments date to 24 February. It’s a pretty big clue that something weird is happening, and would probably tip off anybody who knew about review audits.

**I’d suggest hiding any comments on a question that’s being used as a review audit.**

(Although I don’t know how much, if at all, this is considered a problem: anybody looking at the comment timestamps is probably not a robo-reviewer, and is likely to pass the audit anyway. But I thought it couldn’t hurt to point it out.)

Comment: Yeah.... I had an audit today of a 0 score answe with someone commenting "thanks, upvoting you for that". Honestly most audits, if you take the time to read properly, are transparent

Comment: "...anybody looking at the comment timestamps is probably not a robo-reviewer...": Well, I just failed an audit a few minutes ago for reading the comments of a question that said it was a typo and voting to close as "simple typographical error," but I suppose that statement is true most of the time.

Comment: Audits are designed to catch out those users who repeatedly click 'Looks Ok' or 'No Action Needed', not those that notice these details; because of this, you pretty much passed it before you realised.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you notice that amount of detail **the audit goal was met**. You paid attention, mission accomplished!

Really, audits are *not there for you*. If you can spot the timestamps being iffy, you *already passed the audit*. You are not the kind of reviewer that audits are designed to catch.

Audits are not *meant* to faithfully mimic an actual post in full detail. They are meant to catch out the robo-reviewer, someone who blindly tries to get to the badge at the end of the 1000 reviews as fast as possible.

As such, what you found is [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), possibly even [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Comment: Is there any canonical question/answer for _audits are meant to catch robo-reviewers, not be hard_.  It seems this question is coming up a lot lately.

Comment: That makes sense. I half-suspected that was the case, but I wasn’t sure, so I thought I’d ask.

Comment: @ryanyuyu: it may be time to create one. We could make it [tag:faq-proposed] even.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that sounds good.  So how would we go about doing that?  Just write up a broad enough question for this topic and then answer it (or have mods answer it)?  Basically, who should ask it and who should answer it?

Comment: @ryanyuyu: look at other posts in the [tag:faq] tag, and consult the instructions in the [FAQ index](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow).

Comment: @ryanyuyu: In this case, a question title could be *I can easily see a review is an audit, should I report a bug?* together with a nice question body that shows some examples.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ok thanks.  Obviously, there is discussion at MSE, but this faq-proposed question would still be useful here (with the MSE references)?

Comment: @ryanyuyu: we can either keep pointing people to MSE posts, or create our own here and then dupe close posts to that FAQ. If you feel it helps the post, then by all means use references to relevant MSE posts in that.

Comment: Note that a central repository of "things we know give away audits" just make them less effective at stopping robo-reviewers (of both the human and electronic varieties)

Comment: @BenVoigt: the [current FAQ proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288046/this-review-is-obviously-an-audit-is-this-a-bug) does a good job of not giving away all the ways you can detect an audit, I'd say.

Comment: @BenVoigt: besides, robo-reviewers are, as a whole, not the kind of person to go visit Meta.

Comment: Yes, that's definitely better than (I quote) "a nice question body that shows some examples"

Comment: @BenVoigt: I see what you mean; that wasn't the best idea of mine.

Comment: Had this today, so obviously an audit: http://puu.sh/gDWBA/6fd8b906ef.png