# This review is obviously an audit. Is this a bug?

Tags: support, faq, review-audits

There are many easy ways to tell that a review task is really an audit.  You can just [visit the link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287670/review-audits-exploitable-able-to-see-real-review-stats-before-voting-on-the-re) for more information about the actual post before making a decision.  You can [examine timestamps](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287995/comments-timestamps-can-give-away-a-review-audit).  And there are probably many other tricks/exploits to passing a review audit.

If review audits are so obvious and easy to pass, why do they exist?  Should I report this as a bug?

[Return to FAQ index](/q/251225)

Comment: The "OP" of an "attention test" question usually has no reputation, badges and name like "user21371234", I agree that it is too obvious

Comment: @radrow To notice that means you've been paying attention.  So you passed.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

No, this is not a bug. **Audits are not designed to be challenging**, so there is no need to report "bugs" when you discover clever ways to figure out what review tasks are really audits. There's also no need to report "mistakes" in the review task that give away the fact that it's an audit, even if they don't occur in normal audits. These mistakes are included on purpose.

From the beginning, the [purpose of the review audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work) is twofold: to prevent "robo-reviewing" and help guide new reviewers.

"Robo-reviewing" is *mindless* clicking to quickly process reviews without giving any thought at all to the review.  Often this is to try to quickly process reviews and earn badges with minimum effort.  Audits help stop this mindless reviewing by periodically checking that a reviewer is actually paying attention.  Failing enough audits can lead to a review ban to help prevent future robo-reviewing.  Audits are trying to catch these robo-reviewers, so the [audits should be easy for legitimate reviewers to pass](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171204/are-the-suggested-edit-audits-too-easy/171208#171208).

The other purpose of audits is to help guide new reviewers.  This means that audits are supposed to be clear-cut and even obvious *by design*.  Without such a black-and-white task it would be hard to properly educate new reviewers.  The most important part of audits is teaching reviewers to eliminate spam.  In fact, a lot of [audits are based on spam](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278440/are-there-audits-in-the-triage-review-queue/278512#278512).

**TL;DR**
If you are paying enough attention and spending enough time on a review task to figure out that a review is an audit, then the audit has already done its job.

---

On the other hand, if you feel that a given audit is *absolutely **terrible*** (in either direction – an objectively good post expecting a negative action or an objectively bad post expecting a positive action), simply perform the reverse action on the post itself (downvote if it's bad and upvote if it's good), *outside the review queue*, to prevent that from ever being an audit again.

Because audits are chosen automatically, bad audits can sometimes happen. If you're not sure, you can post on Meta with the [support](/questions/tagged/support) [disputed-review-audits](/questions/tagged/disputed-review-audits) tags for community input.

Additionally, if you spot a user who appears to be robo-reviewing but is somehow passing all the review audits, flag one of their posts for moderator attention and explain the situation. Moderators have the ability to issue manual review bans.

Comment: Just to know, I just receive an audit where the name of the person who answer was completly removed (so it's different than sometimes "user113213" unclickable). So i was absolutly sure it was an audit, and this is detectable with a bot. So whould we report this or it's just something that make it easier to know it's an audit for real person ?