# Audit in review queue: I see you!

Tags: feature-request, review-audits, triage

I've been examining [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7540729) review when I spotted something peculiar:

[image]

Hide yourself better, you impostor!

The workaround seems pretty evident.

Comment: Audits are not meant to be disguised cleverly and be hard to detect, but to prevent 'robo-reviewing'. But I agree, this is a bug.

Comment: If I can guess an audit without reading the q, I am probably becoming more and more "robo-" :)

Comment: Very related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288046/3714930