# Is it a possible bug in the review test?

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close, review-audits

I am not sure if this has been posted before or not, since I couldn't find a proper term to search for (I did try though).

The problem is with the surprise test you get when you are clearing review queue. In my particular case I chose to review close vote queue for duplicate questions for Android tag only since they are the easiest ones to figure out for me.

Then suddenly I get a Off Topic close vote to review. At first I was surprised since I had specifically chosen duplicate close votes only. But I reviewed in anyways and I found out that it was a test. That happened few days ago.

Today I was doing the same and the same thing happened, so I already knew that it was a test.

Although it's a relatively minor flaw, but still reporting it, in case the admins didn't know about that already.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Select Close votes review queue.
2. Select filter and apply duplicate
   question filter and optionally a tag filter(I had Android tag filter
   both the times).
3. Review the questions and wait for the surprise
   test.
4. You will notice that the test doesn't conform to the
   duplicate question filter and can be any kind of close votes
   (Although it seemed to follow tag filter).

**Expected Behavior:**

The test should follow the filters to not reveal that it is a test and not an actual close vote review.

Comment: While review-audits should be unambiguous (even if it needs some thought), and are quite obvious, that might be slightly too obvious. Though it's a long-standing one.... still: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288046/this-review-is-obviously-an-audit-is-this-a-bug

Comment: Review Audit! Yes, that's the term I was looking for. Anyways it should not be that obvious IMO.