# "Editing" a Review Audit's deleted post doesn't automatically pass/fail, why not?

Tags: support, review-audits

I passed a First Post [review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/9320436) this morning, though it was a two step process.

I went to format the unformatted code by clicking the "edit" link, but was met with a mostly blank web page and just the words: "This post has been deleted and can not be edited" (paraphrasing).

Seeing this post was actually an audit I just downvoted it to pass, and I moved on.

I'm wondering, since upvotes/downvotes count for an automatic pass/fail, why doesn't moving for an edit *on a deleted post* result in the same action?

Not sure if my memory is correct, but submitting an edit for a low-quality post does auto-complete similar review audits, right? This post may instead just be bringing to attention the effect deleted answers (and possibly, questions) have on this workflow.

Comment: Kinda related: [This review is obviously an audit. Is this a bug?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288046/4320665)

Comment: I think because an edit on a bad post can still be an improvement, and an edit on a good one can still be an improvement, so how does the system know whether you think a post is good or bad by pressing "edit"?

Comment: @TZHX Again, paraphrasing, but the pass-message on the review audit did specify editing as a method for handling the low-quality answer. 

And if I remember correctly, submitting an edit suggestion does auto-complete these audits..

This may just end up being a post pointing out how deleted posts interrupt this pattern.

Comment: @TZHX regardless of whether you thought it was good or not the fact that you're attempting to edit means you are, in some way, improving the post. If you look at the rules, the `I'm Done` button is available when you `Edit to improve the question's appearance or clarity`. That tells me Trobbins is correct and that editing should probably be an automatic pass of the audit.