# Triage review audit failed because of answer

Tags: support, review-audits

I reviewed today a question on Triage section.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/9845098

In my opinion this question is not bad in fact. It is only when you are looking at answer made just below it.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33032173/offline-audio-recognition-service-with-acrcloud-audio-fingerprinting-api

but then you can see that it's deleted. I don't open question on triage section often, because in most of the cases they're obviously bad or obviously good. Is it a good habit to open a reviewed question and look at all comments and answers?

As said here

[This review is obviously an audit. Is this a bug?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288046/this-review-is-obviously-an-audit-is-this-a-bug)

it should not be called cheating, but I think it should not be obligatory to open each question on triage section and look at whole context. You are reviewing just question, am I right?

Comment: I think what happened was the question received a spam flag and then when the mod deleted it it validated the spam flag so it is using it for an audit.  I am not sure if the mod meant to validate the flag or not as I can see them doing it as the question looks like a setup of a spam seed.

Comment: The audit system is completely broken. If you are lucky, you'll get a few more of these kind of broken audits and then get an automatic review ban. Perhaps we should all stop reviewing entirely so we force SO to finally deal with the broken audit system. But of course they are busy with more important things, like implementing unicorn teams who wear funny hats.

Comment: @Lundin yeah I did get review ban after that audit. I got several audits failed previously, most of them weren't obviously failed. I wish they'll look into that in near future.

Comment: @lundin this is why i stopped reviewing entirely. not worth my time when SO makes it as hard as possible.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That question was what's called a "spam seed" - they have a way of looking like legitimate questions that are only designed for someone else also affiliated to answer.

The moderators have had a fairly good "clean up" (can't go into details) (thanks to everyone that brought it to attention) of such questions and answers - it's just unfortunate that a spam flag was active - which when a question is deleted is automatically marked as helpful by the system.

I've cleared all the spam/offensive flags on that post so it won't be an audit again.

Answer (score 13):

That's not a very good audit - it looks like a perfectly legitimate question. Apparently the moderator who deleted it thought it was posted by someone affiliated with the company, but that's hardly apparent to a normal reviewer.

Comment: I must be strange to think it's a perfectly good audit. The question links are a dead giveaway.