# Editing an audit in the Late Answers queue: Question no longer exists

Tags: bug, review-queues, review-audits

I was spending some time in the Late Answers queue and [was given this audit.](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/11149029)

I attempted to edit the answer, but was taken to a page stating the question no longer exists. It was a basic page with a white background -- no headers, and just the error message printed in black. I didn't take a screenshot and can't reproduce it without receiving another audit.

Upon realizing this was probably an audit, and this error was intentional behavior, I downvoted the question. I received the message indicating this was an audit, but in that message, I was told that **performing an edit was an acceptable choice.**

This leads me to believe that this wasn't expected behavior. Is this a potential bug?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34670520/edit shows _"This post is deleted and cannot be edited"_ (post, not question). I'm fairly sure this question is a duplicate. Seems like a [regression](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193830/why-doesnt-attempting-to-edit-count-as-a-pass-for-a-review-audit) of an old issue though.

Comment: You mean the post we're trying to edit is a duplicate, or my question is a duplicate?

Comment: Yours. :) Try searching the web for `review audit "This post is deleted and cannot be edited."` or something. And wow, that search shows up a lot of Stack Exchange scraping sites.

Comment: Found it. [This question was asked 2 years ago on StackExchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177130/review-audits-with-deleted-posts). The only answer suggests that *ideally* hitting the edit button should trigger the "Congratulations!" message, but also that "this works too" -- I disagree, and so do other users in those comments.

Comment: Probably related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288046/this-review-is-obviously-an-audit-is-this-a-bug (Not as in, it's the same issue, just a related post.)

Comment: You chose... okay.  Audits aren't designed to catch people who are avoiding audits, they're designed to catch robo reviewers who blindly accept anything that crosses in front of them.  The fact that you thought about the review means you passed it, so a leaky audit doesn't necessarily equate to a bug.

Comment: @Will I'm not concerned about the choice I made, because I agree -- the point of the audit was achieved. The message says editing was an acceptable choice, but upon editing, I received an error on a blank page and I have to perform some other action to pass the audit. It's not the end of the world by any means, but this is a textbook example of a bug.

Comment: Oh, missed that wrinkle.  Muhbad.