# Audits are revealed ahead of time by missing user data

Tags: bug, review-audits

While spending time in the review queue I noticed that some audits (if not all) are immediately recognizable by missing user name and image.

[image: Example screen shot of missing user.]

This made me change my normal review behaviour and made me think about specifically as an audit. In my eyes this undermines the intended effect of audits.

Is this intended behaviour or am I missing something here?

Comment: [Yes, this is intended](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288046/this-review-is-obviously-an-audit-is-this-a-bug).

Comment: @Glorfindel - So y'all are allowed to say "Yes" to this question.

Comment: Well, a good question can be asked by a user that later deletes their account.  But that's an exceedingly small percentage of questions.  The audit was successful, however, because you were paying attention, and that's what it is checking for.