# Comments on Documentation review audit fails

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, review-audits

I just had a [review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/106002?filter-tags=ios) in the Documentation Proposed Changes Review Queue and successfully identified it as a low quality edit.

But before flagging it, I wanted to leave a comment and got this error message:

[image: screenshot]

Is this actually intended for Documentation's review audits? If this happens for every audit, bots might use this to identify audits.

Comment: Related: [This review is obviously an audit. Is this a bug?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288046/this-review-is-obviously-an-audit-is-this-a-bug), but probably not a duplicate since Documentation review is so new and could still have a few kinks to work out.  This really could be a bug and not the usual "audits are supposed to be obvious".

Comment: @ryanyuyu comments are possible in the other queues. Commenting on a bad post makes you pass the audit

Comment: I was just providing some context for the normal case of audits being obvious.  I agree that this particular situation seems unintended.

Comment: On my plate to fix...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next build will fix this error, making the audit a pass if the reviewer attempts to leave a comment.

Thank you for reviewing responsibly and leaving this bug report!