# I failed an audit that I think was not very obvious

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits

I review a fair amount for StackOverflow and have never failed any audits until I started reviewing in the re-open queue. I pay close attention to the posts, but every once in a while I think that a post should stay closed, but it flags me and says that I should re-open the question as there were no serious problems with it. I would specifically like to ask about [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/14457416). The question was initially closed as Primarily Opinion Based. I voted to keep it closed because, while it is a good question, there is seemingly no one correct answer to the question. My belief was confirmed in the accepted answer which was acknowledged as being an opinion based answer when the answerer wrote

> IMO, vector looks a good prospect for your need. It supports index-based element access as the elements are stored in continuous memory addresses. Has flexibility with size.

This would, at least to me, imply that this question is somewhat opinion based. I'm wondering either if this audit was flawed, or why this question should be reopened? It's not an obviously awful question, but I think that when there's a legitimate argument as to why a question should stay closed that it at least not be made an audit.

Comment: Erm, the question is **not closed and has never been closed**

Comment: @DavidPostill it was in the reopen vote queue. I know that it's not closed now as it was being used for an audit, but wouldn't it have to have been closed to be in that queue?

Comment: @DavidPostill Ah. I did go to the question to check if it should "remain closed" where I guess it had never been closed. Having said that, isn't that somewhat unfair? I was working under the assumption that it had already been closed and I thought that that rationale was still valid insofar as the question is still primarily opinion based.

Comment: Audits lie. See the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40373397/timeline)

Comment: But if the question was never closed..... It should be reopened HAD it been closed

Comment: Why should this question not be closed? I feel as if it is primarily opinion based.

Comment: Is it really though? We know exactly the requirements, we know which metric he wants (speed). There is little opinion into what is fastest.... No?

Comment: But from the answers it seemed like there was not one proper answer to the question especially indicated by the "IMO" in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is not primarily opinion-based, and the answer isn't pure opinion either. Rather, following the principles of [Good Subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/), it *backs up* its recommendation with reasoning.

So you can treat this as a learning experience in what makes a good Q/A pair on SO for subjects that don't reduce to "what will actually compile?"

Comment: I agree and I've learned that now. I guess I'm also just disappointed that I failed an audit. On the whole I think the audits are fine, I was just disappointed that I failed one while paying attention.

Comment: @EliSadoff: Audit failures happen to the best of us, even diamond mods. As long as you don't run into a review ban, you can figure you don't need to worry *too* much, just keep doing your best.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words and the explanation.

Answer (score -1):

<s>I think that "Too Broad" would have been better for that. Aside from that, I think that you **correctly** reviewed as "Leave Closed". I've now flagged it to properly put it in Close Votes. You know, as a non-audit.</s> I've retracted my flag upon realizing that this action was incorrect.

The question has a specific list of possible implementations at the end, and it's worth having on the site.

It's worth noting, however, that **the post in question has been selected as an audit 3 times, and 2 out of 3 times the reviewer failed.** Review audits aren't supposed to be that hard; they're supposed to have an [obvious correct choice](/q/288046/6388243) that can be decided within a minute of looking at the question.

Comment: So… what exactly is wrong with this post?

Comment: The question in question is not off-topic, this is a good audit that did its job.

Comment: @TinyGiant um… **no**. It's asking for a specific software recommendation, you need to at least make a decent argument that it's on-topic.

Comment: The closest to a software recommendation the question could come would be if it were _"which library should I use for this"_, but the OP is asking _"which **data structure** should I use for this"_. The latter is not a request for an external library. The code in the question indicates (though it could've been stated more explicitly, in text) that they're at least open to using the Standard Library and Boost. So, not off-topic.

Comment: @CodeCaster that still leaves "Too Broad" though. Standard Library is huge in Java; you can probably bet there's at least a dozen classes that can accomplish any decently common task, all unique in their own way. Not that I'm familiar with the C standard library…

Comment: The requirements are specific, I don't see how it is too broad.

Comment: Wait, nevermind, I just realized that it has a specific list at the end. I'll have this edited in a few minutes.

Comment: @TinyGiant citation: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288046/6388243

Comment: @Stephen thanks for adding the citation to your answer, though I believe that this is a clear cut case of a good on-topic question. Users repeatedly failing the audit does not mean that the audit is not doing its job, it can mean that it is doing a good job of catching robo-reviewers though.

Comment: @TinyGiant it still opens with "I need a structure as follows [image] this is my requirement"—it's easy to mistake that for something too broad or a software rec. The list at the end is really the only thing that keeps it somewhat on-topic.

Comment: I don't think it is easy to mistake if you actually read the entire post, if you stop at the image then yeah, but then the audit is doing its job because you aren't reading the entire post.