# Reopen audits too obvious for having a positive score?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-audits, reopen-closed

According to my experience participating in the Reopen queue, the review audit is too obvious compared to audits in other queues. It always displays a positive score for the post, which hardly ever happen on non-audit review items.

I just reviewed tens of my recent Reopen reviews and found that ALL posts with a positive score are audits.

I agree that audits shouldn't be too hard to be told apart, or otherwise it would catch a lot of good reviewers only with a differentiating opinion in mind. But at least shall we anonymize the vote count and display a zero, like audits in other queues do?

Comment: [Relevant faq question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288046/7296893). Removing the votes isn't a bad idea in my opinion. Perhaps it would even be helpful to have some awful questions as audits with 2-3 upvotes, to make sure people aren't reopening anything that's upvoted (and there are enough upvoted closed questions that certainly shouldn't be reopened).

Comment: Um... I'm trying to get this clear in my head. You've raised posts on meta regarding audits that aren't obvious or otherwise unfair. Apart from the dodgy ones - you recognise they're just there to make sure you're paying attention and not over zealously clicking a button. Your suggestion now is to actually make it even less obvious? Why? (There are bad audits - we all know that and it's not great - but why oh why, would we want to make it even harder?)

Comment: @JonClements But don't you think showing a positive score in a queue where most of the questions are of bad quality makes it *too* obvious?

Comment: @JonClements Question edited to regard my primary argument point.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth We can even send one post into the same queue twice or thrice and see if the community's opinion agrees. And if it is then the post may be used as an audit for a "known quality". E.g. if a high-scored post received 10 close votes after sending to close queue twice then it's a known "should be closed" post.

Comment: @JonClements Think of me an anonymized or a new user that you don't know at all. My previous complaints about disputed audits have nothing ito do with this one.

Comment: @iBug hi new user - thanks for bringing it up but review audits are meant to be obvious and check to make sure you're not just mashing buttons - you passed - so nothing to worry about. While audits could certainly be better - the less obvious/dubious ones are a matter of angst amongst the community and be a time sink for everyone on meta discussing disputes (an experienced reviewer with a very similar name to yours has been frustrated more than once in non obvious audits)- I'm not sure unnecessary obfuscation of information is really required.

Comment: @JonClements Well then just leave this post alone.

Comment: @iBug I think your first (and less hostile sounding) comment regarding status-bydesign is probably about right - however this a feature request you're making and I'm still hoping for why this *would be better* given the points I've made and your experience.

Comment: @JonClements May my mind went incoherent for some time.

Comment: I just passed [this Reopen review audit](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/942230), but it didn't show any votes: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UICcC.png