# Can we see what review queue test questions were used as "tests" for?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I try to complete all 20 reviews per queue each day, and every so often I get a test review. When answered successfully, I get a messaged saying I passed the test and it shows that the question was deleted, or it doesn't show anything. See the two examples I experienced today below:

[image]

[image]

None of these are descriptive enough to tell me what they were closed for, or why the question/answer at hand was "a test". I have tried flagging a question, which I knew would be a test, as a random flag which didn't necessarily make sense in that situation and it still says I passed. This doesn't help me or anyone trying to improve their reviewing skills going forward.

So, why aren't the tests more descriptive? If something is "unclear" vs. "too broad" for example, I would like to know which one it was closed or deleted for.

Comment: @Kendra I just gave that post a read and I don't see my question being related. Yes they have to do with review audits but that one is specifically about why are some audits so easy, where mine is asking about why there aren't more detail about some of the audits

Comment: I feel the answer lies easily in _"From the beginning, the purpose of the review audits is twofold: to prevent "robo-reviewing" and help guide new reviewers."_ but I see where it may not be so obvious an answer.

Comment: @Kendra I see where you're going with that, i guess my main question lies in my last sentence then

Comment: You do know the audits are not hand-picked, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This review is obviously an audit. Is this a bug?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288046/this-review-is-obviously-an-audit-is-this-a-bug)

Answer (score 5):

> None of these are descriptive enough to tell me what they were closed for...

Audits in the review queues are only meant to make sure you're paying attention. They aren't making sure you're using the exact correct close reason (sometimes more than one applies anyway), only that you recognize that the question should be or closed. It's meant to stop people who just want the review badges from just hitting "Looks OK" (or whatever the fastest option is in a particular queue) without looking.

> ...why the question/answer at hand was "a test".

Audits are chosen automatically by the system. Posts in which the community agreed on the quality on the post are potential audits. For example, an answer with a score of 20 and no down votes or flags could be an audit as well as a question that only got down votes and was closed as spam.

Everyone gets audit posts occasionally, again to make sure you're paying attention.

> This doesn't help me or anyone trying to improve their reviewing skills going forward.

I think if you hang around meta and pay attention to the discussions on flagging, close votes, and closed questions you'll get a good idea of how you should be reviewing posts. There are also tags for specific queues (like [triage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/triage)) as well as [FAQs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faq).

Comment: Shouldn't this information be added to the message box telling that a review was a text. The brevity of the message box in there left me with a lot of questions, making me researching to this question.

Comment: @The_spider Maybe adding a link to a FAQ about audits for those that want more information would make sense.

Answer (score 2):

All the audits can realistically test for is if you're actually paying attention.  It doesn't really matter where they come from; so long as you recognize that a link-only answer is *not* "Looks Good", the audits have fulfilled their role.