# The "New Contributor" banner is making review audits easier

Tags: discussion, review-audits, new-users

When I was going through the review queue for First Posts, I noticed that all of the user badges had the "New Contributor" banner, of course. But for audits that the users actually aren't new, the banner doesn't show up, which makes passing audits a LOT easier.

What do you guys suggest we should do to solve this?

Comment: _"which makes passing audits a LOT easier"_ By which means exactly? Does the banner have an impact regarding judgment of content quality in 1st place?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm guessing they mean it makes *spotting* audits easier. I'm not sure this needs solving though since there's usually something off about audit posts anyway. Normally the response to this sort of post is, "Congratulations, you spotted the audit!" but maybe this is too obvious.

Comment: @BSMP TBH, I have no clue. Thus I placed that comment. I am not working on triage review  queues or such, just another [tag:tag] cerberus.

Comment: I would suggest to not show the New Contributor banner in review queues at all.

Comment: I really don't see the point of showing it is a post of a new user because that has been there already in the text on top: _"This is the first question asked by a new user. Help them learn to use the site by reviewing their post."_ If we really need the _Be Nice_ reminder it should be added to that.

Comment: @Stijn I am not sure if I agree with the content of duplicate, since this is a little bit to obvious for robo reviewers, hence I think robo reviewing (not looking at content, only looking for new contributor banner) is still possible.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt you may be right. You're certainly not the only one with that opinion, [the review task](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/close/19989) from my CV has 3 'Leave Open' votes and 1 'Close' vote.

Comment: The first post review was always rather questionable to begin with. By now, it is blatantly obvious that those reviews are pointless and do not stop crap from entering the site, so those reviews is just a waste of time. And we should not even mention the first post automated audits.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

General, the opinion about audits is, we shouldn't care if there are indicators for an audit.

From the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288047/2441442):

> No, audits are not designed to be challenging, so there is no need to report "bugs" for clever ways to figure out what review tasks are really audits.

But in this case it isn't a very clever thing. A robo reviewer just need to look if the banner is present and can continue robo reviewing.

As @Thomas [commented](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373320/the-new-contributor-banner-is-making-review-audits-easier#comment625604_373320):

> I would suggest to not show the New Contributor banner in review queues at all.

This seems reasonable for me, since the indicator shouldn't change our review behavior, so it is imho irrelevant.

Answer (score 6):

You realized this because *you were paying pretty close attention* to what you were doing. That .. completely obviates the need for an audit; had you *failed* said audit, it would have been because your reaction was different than the consensus (and ultimate action taken on the post). E.g. "That looked like an answer to me!"

Audits catch people that are looking for unicorn patterns in the clouds while clicking buttons in review. Had you noticed the new contributor indicator in the clouds, well, you would probably need to spend more time *outside*, but I digress.

[image: Waving hand made out of clouds]

It's not a problem. Audits are guard rails, folks fast asleep tend not to see what color they are when they plow into them.