# Should selection of "check if you are paying attention" review audits be filter aware?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits

I noticed that if I apply a filter when reviewing questions, the occasional "check if you are paying attention" audit post does not necessarily conform to that filter.

As an example, if I review "first posts" and filter on "answers only", it will happen that questions will be shown from time to time, making it very clear that these are audit posts.

Since my understanding is that the purpose of the audit system is to make sure everybody is paying attention, should it be made a bit harder by being filter-aware? Not sure how "important" this is or how well the audit mechanism works or if it can be gamed anyway, but my feeling was that this may make it unnecessarily easy.

On the other hand, the fact that I noticed may be proof enough that I was sufficiently paying attention?

Curious what others think...

Comment: From the [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288047/11682469) to the FAQ [This review is obviously an audit. Is this a bug?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288046/11682469): "**Audits are not designed to be challenging**..." They are there to catch robo-reviewers.

Comment: If you notice that a post doesn't conform to your filter, then you are paying attention, and the audit has served it's purpose. Audits are meant to catch people just clicking random buttons and not doing anything else.