# Banned from review queues for a non-question (in my eyes)

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, review-suspension, first-post-review

I have been banned on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/30484142 (the audit preview might be misleading since the question has been edited, see [the 3rd revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/69979522/3) of the question instead)

I simply clicked on share feedback ...

What I am absolutely sure about:

There were **no comments and no upvotes when displayed to me for the review**.

To me it looks like a pure information, not a question - that's why I wanted to share feedback.

May I explain how I read this:

Title = "Fix for ..." without question mark sounds to me like "I am describing the fix for the error"

Within the body the explanation is "This is because ... there is a bug" - again no question mark ...

That's why this post does not look like a question to me - it would if e.g. the last sentence were "Could this be a bug introduced ...?"

If I had seen all the comments and upvotes I would have clicked ok - although I would have believed that this was no question.

Up to now I never understood why I got banned - but this time I am asking for an explanation.

Comment: "What I am absolutly sure about: There were **no comments and no upvotes when displayed to me for the review.**" Because it was an audit meant to test you. "To me it looks like a pure information not a question" While it does not contain a question mark, the title "Fix for "fatal: Authentication failed for"" indicates that it's about how to fix the error. And the question body does *not* contain the fix.  "If I had seen all the comments and upvotes..." Judge the posts on their own merits, not based on comments or votes (upvotes not always reflect post quality or suitability for SO).

Comment: Thanks for the answer - your are absolutly right to not judge on others comments etc. But as I never understood why I have got banned I do look what others say. May I explain how I read this: Title = "Fix for ..." without question mark sounds to me like "I am describing the fix for the error" - and within the body the explanation is "This is because ... there is a bug" - again no question mark ... That's why this post does not look like a question to me - it would be if e.g. the last sentence were "Could this be a bug introduced ...?"

Comment: It looks like everyone else that voted on the question understood that the author was looking for a workaround or fix for the bug. However, I can see how this post kind of looks like failed attempt at a self Q&A with the first half explaining the issue and the second half explaining that they found where the problem is.

Comment: @BSMP - I am pretty sure, that, if I had looked at the post while looking myself for an explanation of the error, I would have upvoted it - but this would have been another context. Reviewing a post has other criteria - as I understood it.

Comment: Yeah I sympathise with you that this is a very misleading audit. But I would stress that if a post looks sketchy like this, it is always best to open them outside of review. Audits fall flat like that real quick. It is not true that you got banned for this though; you got sent on vacation for multiple audit failures. This was just the one that tipped the scales.

Comment: @Gimby: As I got banned already several times, it just needs one failure to get banned for a month ... And as I said: I never understood why ... I am sure I am doing the audits with enough concentration and am reading the post thoroughly ... somehow it feels like being treated unfair by a teacher again and again ... I am too old for that ... I doubt I will do reviews again ...

Comment: I agree this question could be misleading (aka bad audit). FWIW, there's another user who failed this audit before you. For now, I have edited the question to explicitly mention the question. As for the current review suspension, we can only wait for mods' response.

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks! - With the current text I certainly would have clicked "OK"

Comment: The eternal review trick question: a poorly asked question about a newly introduced bug in a popular developer resource, that becomes popular since hundreds of people experience it at the same time and flock to Stack Overflow, leading the algorithm to think it's a good question. We've had multiple different reports of this exact type of question leading to review bans.

Comment: @RyanM Thank you. I think your answer and Erik As comment are good explanations why this question was rated as OK by the "algorithms" ... still I am curious what the mods will say and if I get unbanned ...

Comment: You are right this was a bad audit item. As it was written when you reviewed it, it did not ask a question and deserved to be downvoted/closed as unclear. The system that picks audit items, unfortunately, only looks at the question's score, comments, and answers. It isn't smart enough to read the contents and understand if a question is good enough or not. However, you also aren't banned from one failed audit, unless a moderator manually applied the ban. If you were banned instantly after failing this audit, it means you have failed quite a few other audits recently as well.

Comment: @Ike - At the end of the day you still choose the incorrect review response, better care to view the question in another tab, might have prevented that from happening. It’s unusual to be in a situation where you are review banned after one failed audit.  It means you failed numerous audits in the past.

Comment: @SecurityHound - indeed that is sth I learned now: to watch a post outside the review - especially if it is about a bug. Yes, I have been banned several times - and as I said in my post: I never understood why - maybe my understanding differs too much from SO algorithm standards ... that's ok. But as I already said: I doubt I will do reviews again.

Comment: @Ike - You could always open up questions in another tab, avoid failing reviews, and skipping any review your not positive

Comment: @SecurityHound ... this is kind of cheating - isn't it? And it is the opposite of what Jeanne Dark wrote in her comment: "Judge the posts on their own merits, not based on comments or votes (upvotes not always reflect post quality or suitability for SO)" ... reading this again the part in the brackets supports somehow what Erik A wrote   :-/

Comment: How is it cheating if you do it for every review? Audits were designed to be passed, the algorithm, selects candidate that are so obvious 99% of the time. @Jeanne basically indicated that your review wasn’t accurate, and the question was obviously about how to solve a problem, one that was within scope. I would agree based on the revision you indicated you reviewed. After a couple dozen audits your able to sense something is an audit anyways.

Comment: Relevant: [This review is obviously an audit. Is this a bug?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288046/11682469), [There is no shame in using "Skip"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/11682469). The purpose of audits is to catch robo-reviewers. Already noticing that a review may be an an audit shows that you did pay attention and not mindlessly clicked something like "Looks ok". My remark about judging posts on their own merit is about non-audits. Just a warning, because people upvote off-topic questions or NAAs, or comment that an on-topic question was off-topic, to name a few examples.

Comment: If I define "paying attention" for myself, it has a large overlap with "not making decisions based on incomplete data". I can't speak for others, but I can't usually make review decisions with only what I see in the review screen, I need to scan everything. Context matters, and discussions in comments and other existing answers can provide that context. Sometimes even the post edit history.

Comment: As a practical example, recently there was a discussion about Vulkan questions being very hard to provide example code for. If I would see such a question in review my gut feeling might be that a question needs to be closed for lacking debugging details. However if I then see the comments or maybe even existing answers which have no problem understanding the question, because other Vulkan devs know that their world is different, I will without hesitation ignore my gut and hit skip.